# Python - Pandas compare columns with NaN returns False

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 DataFrames, one is called `old` and another is called `new`.
The 2 DataFrames have multiple columns, but I am interested in column called `ADDTEXT`. When you open the 2 files in Excel and compare the `ADDTEXT` columns, they are completely identical.
When I do `old == new` in Python, it returns `False`. When I do `new['ADDTEXT'].equals(old['ADDTEXT'])` it returns `True`.

Why don't they both return True since both columns contain only the `NaN` values in them?

**Example output:**

```
>>> new = pd.read_excel('3.8_self_input_data.xlsx')
>>>
>>>
>>> old = pd.read_excel('3.7_self_input_data.xlsx')
>>>
>>> old['ADDTEXT']
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
        ...
13630    NaN
13631    NaN
13632    NaN
13633    NaN
13634    NaN
Name: ADDTEXT, Length: 13635, dtype: object
>>>
>>> new['ADDTEXT']
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
        ...
13630    NaN
13631    NaN
13632    NaN
13633    NaN
13634    NaN
Name: ADDTEXT, Length: 13635, dtype: object
>>>
>>> new['ADDTEXT'] == old['ADDTEXT']
0        False
1        False
2        False
3        False
4        False
         ...
13630    False
13631    False
13632    False
13633    False
13634    False
Name: ADDTEXT, Length: 13635, dtype: bool
>>>
>>> new['ADDTEXT'].equals(old['ADDTEXT'])
True
```

Comment: Generally speaking NULL!=NULL I assume the same applies to NaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### NaN != NaN

Instead of *just* using `.equals()`, you can use `isna()` on the two columns:

```
(new['ADDTEXT'].eq(old['ADDTEXT']) | (new['ADDTEXT'].isna() & old['ADDTEXT'].isna()))
```

Basically that reads: return True for each item if both items are equal or both are NaN.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what if in the column I'll have a value "Yes"? Or anything else? How do I compare the whole column against the other column regardless of what data are in there (can be mixed NaNs, strings, numbers, etc.)?

Comment: So you want `"Yes"`, `1`, and `True` to all be coereced to `True`, and `"No"`, `0`, and `False` to all be coerced to `False`?

Comment: Not exactly. If on index 1 in first column is "Yes", or "Whatever else as string or number or NaN or any other type" is also on index 1 in the second column, return True.

Comment: Will you please open a _new_ question for that. And give an example dataframe and your expected output? Because in this comment thread as it is it's hard to discuss issues like this...(remember to accept this answer if you do)